# XMLWorkerHelper giving error in Java

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, xmlhelper

I'm trying to create PDF using iText in Java. When i tried to write HTML tags in my PDF it created like `<a href="https://www.google.co.in">Google</a>` instead of Google(as a link). After searching net i tried using `XMLWorkerHelper`. But my eclipse giving error as `The method parseXHtml(PdfWriter, Document, InputStream) from the type XMLWorkerHelper refers to the missing type PdfWriter` I'm not getting what is this error.

```
try {
    String k = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>";
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Test.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
    document.open();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(k.getBytes());
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
    document.close();
    file.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to know which PdfWriter i should use. I'm using `xmlworker-5.4.1.jar` jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.itextpdf.tool/xmlworker/5.4.2/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/XMLWorkerHelper.java?av=f), it looks like it is depending on `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter` which is part of the `itextpdf-5.4.1.jar`

Comment: Why not use the latest version of iText, [5.4.4](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/544)?

Comment: No special reason. Sathesh was referring to 5.4.1